# Javascript/jQuery limiting toggleClass to 4

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to stop a user from selecting more than four free seats with toggleClass and a length attached but can't accomplish this and haven't found a solution that works for. Thanks.

**JSfiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/xgrorxnp/1/

**HTML**

```
  <td class='n' id='1_A'>T</td>
  <td class='n' id='1_B'>F</td>
  <td class='n' id='1_C'>T</td>
  <td class="row_num">1</td>
  <td class='n' id='1_D'>T</td>
  <td class='n' id='1_E'>F</td>
  <td class='n' id='1_F'>T</td>
```

**My Attempt**

```
$('.n:contains(\'F\')').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
    $(this).toggleClass('selected', !$this.hasClass('selected') &&
        $('.n:contains(\'F\') .selected').length < 4);
    });
```

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to accomplish. Can you throw together a Fiddle so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: _"I'm trying to stop a user from selecting more than four free seats"_ There appear to be only two elements which contain `"F"` ? Is requirement for a maximum of four `td` elements within `tr` to have `selected` `className` ?

Comment: The the table rows i've shown are only one row of twenty three to give an idea and yes that is the requirement I am trying to get. I'm not 100% sure how to use jsfiddle but I tried https://jsfiddle.net/xgrorxnp/

Comment: Yes, the requirement is to limit `.selected` to a maximum of four per `td` element ?

Comment: Yes that's what I would like it to do.

Comment: @CallumRocks See post; try adjusting selector to `$('.n:contains(\'F\').selected', this.parentElement).length < amount);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the space within selector `$('.n:contains(\'F\') .selected')`, which attempts to match `.n` element which has descandant `.selected` , rather than `.n` which has `.selected` `className` itself

Try substituting

`$('.n:contains(\'F\').selected', this.parentElement)`

for

`$('.n:contains(\'F\') .selected').length < 4);`

e.g.;

```
    $(this).toggleClass('selected', !$this.hasClass('selected') &&
        $('.n:contains(\'F\').selected', this.parentElement).length < amount);
```

where `this.parentElement` is the `context` to match, or the `parentElement` : `tr` element of clicked `td` element

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xgrorxnp/3/